# "Use" vs. "usage"

Tags: differences, nouns

When should one use *usage* instead of *use*? Examples?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tend to agree with Peter Shor:

> The word *prevarication* is not in common use.

But:

> The word *prevarication* is not common usage.

(A sentence that presumably refers to some previous *use* of prevarication in a non-standard way.) Note how dropping the preposition changes the context of the phrase.

A question that can be asked is whether usage has any really useful use, other than for pedants.

Comment: My gut feeling was to agree with you and Peter, but [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+in+common+use%2Cnot+in+common+usage%2Cnot+common+usage&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows *not* **in** *common usage* is more common than without "in". But neither version is anywhere near as common as *not in common use*.

Answer (score 38):

*Usage* is how something is used; the fact of something being used is *use*; the degree to which something is used is *utilization*.

> The word *prevarication* is not in common usage.
>   The use of safety belts is mandatory.
>   The utilization of safety belts has reached 70%.

Comment: I'd agree with the first two definitions there, but I've never heard that the third is true.  Can you cite anything for that?

Comment: I'd disagree with your first example; I'd say "The word *prevarication* is not in common use." but "The usage of the word *prevarication* has changed."

Comment: I've always understood `utilization` to mean "used in a manner other than intended". i.e., One might *use* a hammer to drive or remove a nail, or *utilize* a hammer as a door stop or paperweight.

Comment: Would you say "The use of" "The usage of" or "using" ... this method has been shown to be a good alternative.

Comment: @skan — “use”, definitely.  You are not explaining anything about the manner in which the method is used.  I tend to favor “use” any way, as the shorter, more common word.

Answer (score 8):

I thought to excerpt this article because it mentions the etymology, and concludes by using **use** and **usage** in the same sentence.

https://coachdes.wordpress.com/2005/10/24/english-use-and-usage/:

> What is the difference between ‘use’ and usage’? Both come from the same Latin word ***usus*** (noun), which in turn is from the verb *uti -* to use. So how do they differ?
>
> The difference is subtle but *useful*.
>
> The noun ‘**use**’ comes from the verb ‘use’, meaning *to employ for a
>   given purpose or put into action*, and larger dictionaries will list
>   many variations and adaptations of that basic meaning. Examples are:
>   ‘I use a keyboard to type in these words’         ‘I use a knife and
>   fork to eat my dinner’,  ‘I use short words in speaking with small
>   children, because they probably won’t understand long words’.     So
>   the noun ‘use’ (with the ‘s’ as in ‘goose’, not, as for the verb, as
>   in ‘cruise’) means a given purpose or application. Examples would be: 
>   ‘The English language is in common use around the world’ ,     ‘I put
>   my keyboard to good use’.
>
> For the noun ‘**usage**’ the basic dictionary definition can look
>   pretty much the same as that for ‘use’, but with ‘usage’ there is a
>   sense of ‘continued’ or ‘common’ use. And with language, the
>   distinction is that ‘usage’ is the way the language is actually used,
>   as distinct from what might look correct if you try to construct a
>   sentence or phrase from a dictionary and grammar book. Examples would
>   be:     ‘Although old-fashioned grammarians say you should never split
>   an infinitive, that is done every day in common usage.’ and      ‘I
>   was taught at school that every sentence must have a verb, but actual
>   usage shows that many excellent writers include in their work
>   ‘sentences’ without verbs, such as ‘His arrival at any gathering was
>   always a dramatic event. Bold. Arresting.’
>
> How *useful* is this distinction? Well, in everyday life it probably
>   doesn’t have a lot of application, but for me it is an *interesting*
>   distinction, partly because of the origin of the words. As indicated
>   above, both **use** and **usage** come to us from the Latin
>   ***usus***, but **usage** has arrived via Old French, from the 14th century AD.
>
> But there is a very practical consideration here.
>
> Anyone who wants to be a highly confident, fluent speaker of English
>   would do well to develop an insatiable curiosity to know the
>   appropriate **usage**, which is a way of employing language at a
>   higher level than technically correct **use**.
>
> For those who want to have a ready reference on this subject, I
>   recommend The New Fowler’s Modern English Usage.

Comment: Would you say "for medical use" or "for medical usage" ?

Comment: @skan "use" is the only one of the two that means "purpose of using", so I think you would say "for medical use".

Answer (score 4):

*Usage* is also more commonly used than *use* to specify a quantity; for example, [electricity usage](http://www.t2c.org.uk/saving-energy/electricity-usage/).

Answer (score 0):

- *Usage*: rules of language
- *Use*: meaningful communicative behavior

Answer (score 0):

Usage: rules of language
Use: meaningful communicative behaviour

The term usage refers to conventions, most often to those of language. Thus, 'English usage' or 'French usage' refers to the conventions of those languages, respectively.  When we refer to 'word usage', we mean the conventions for using words; when we refer to 'use of words', we mean only the employment of words:  'This text describes the principles of word usage'.  'He is noted for his frequent use of wrong words'.

People frequently use usage when they should use use.  The noun usage should not be substituted for use when the meaning is 'the employment of' – even if you think it sounds more 'sophisticated'.  It is not correct to say that "the wise usage of computers saved the company money" or 'usage of insulation can save fuel'.  In both instances, use is the appropriate word.

http://www.grammarmudge.cityslide.com/articles/article/992333/8566.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Usage of** is used more for plural/non-plural quantity:

> It tracks mobile usage of the Netflix app in 30 international regions including India, Brazil, the UK, and Malaysia, where it has a sample size that makes up a statistically significant portion of the local device population. It also tracks usage of the Netflix app in the US, but Android devices are the minority there and the data capture a snapshot of overall usage.
> -Business Insider

https://lengusa.com/search/usage%20of

**use of** is more like for 'using'

> Theresa May said there was “no practicable alternative to the use of force” to stop the use of alleged use of chemical weapons by Bashar al-Assad, as the UK joined the US and France in launching strikes against targets in Syria associated with the use of such substances.
> -Independent

https://lengusa.com/search/use%20of

When you search them alone, **usage** is more like 'being used'

> Lidl UK said its animal-welfare policy banned routine usage of antibiotics and its suppliers were required to monitor usage through adherence to the Red Tractor scheme’s antibiotic use standards. A spokesman said: “We are committed to meeting sector targets and fully support the disclosure of antibiotic usage. -
> Independent

https://lengusa.com/search/usage

and **use** has so many meanings.

https://lengusa.com/search/use