# using "Usage" or "Use"

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Use” vs “usage”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34712/use-vs-usage)

As a non-native speaker, I have trouble deciding whether to use 'use' or 'usage'.

> The aim of this paper is to demonstrate a working prototype of a wireless sensor network [...] for industrial (use|usage).

Are both versions equivalent, or is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both**, *use* and *usage*, are equally correct.

Comment: ... but whenever *use* is possible, *usage* shouldn't appear: hence, "... industrial use" is a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

"The aim of this paper is to demonstrate a working prototype of a wireless sensor network [...] for industrial USE." sounds more appropriate.

USAGE is mostly used for quantitative figures e.g. the USAGE this month was XXX MB.