# What is the difference between use and usage?

Tags: verbs, nouns, uncountable-nouns

Can use and usage be written interchangeably? 
Does use include usage under its scope? 
Does usage has more specific meaning attached to it?
If there is any difference, tell me one striking difference so that whenever i tend to use them interchangeably I can avoid doing so.

Comment: Search the site. This has been asked before.

Comment: [Same question here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69913/using-usage-or-use?r=SearchResults&s=2|60.3739) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34712/use-vs-usage?r=SearchResults&s=1|72.5035)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Use" vs. "usage"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34712/use-vs-usage)

Comment: To a fair extent,  it answered my question. But can you use "use" and "usage" in a single sentence to make the difference more clear. I am also thinking on it but am not getting an example right now.

Comment: Since I *use* air conditioning in the Summer, that *usage* shows up in higher electric bills for July and August.